# Event listener not running in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I’m having an issue with Chrome. I have tried to create a button that adds a new `<input>` tag when the button is pressed. Now, the below code works totally fine on Internet Explorer, however in Chrome nothing happens at all.

I also get no errors in the console; the function just doesn’t seem to run.

I’ve tried replacing the `$("#addto").append(input1);` with just `alert("hello world");`, just to see if the code ran at all, and it doesn’t.

I’ve also just noticed that this works fine if you put the JavaScript inside a `<script>` tag on the HTML page but it’s only when it’s in a separate `.js` file that it won’t work.

It looks like my Chrome version isn’t properly working. I’ve downloaded Chrome Portable and that has fixed the issue.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var buttonElement = document.getElementById("addinput");

  if (buttonElement) {
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', addinput);
  }

  function addinput() {
    var input1 = '<div class="input-group mb-3"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Name</span></div><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"></div>';
    
    $("#addto").append(input1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button id="addinput" type="button" class="btn btn-default">add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This works fine for me once I added `jQuery` and `#addto`. To go off your edit, is the seperate file included in the html with a `<script>` tag?

Comment: "but its only when it's in a separate js file that it wont work." Did you include that file?

Comment: @Jimenemex yes the file is in a script tag. and i know it's working as there are other function being call that draw a bar chart that shows. Also this all works in internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload=function() {
  var buttonElement = document.getElementById("addinput");

  if (buttonElement) {
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', addinput);
  }

  function addinput() {
    var input1 = '<div class="input-group mb-3"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Name</span></div><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"></div>';
    $("#addto").append(input1);
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="addinput" type="button" class="btn btn-default">add</button>
        <div id="addto"></div>
    </div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your code actually works

Comment: I know it does but only in internet explorer or if the JavaScript is in the same file as the HTML in a <script> tag if its in a separate JS file chrome will not work.

Comment: I've done the test with multiple files... same result
https://embed.plnkr.co/yfdWyR6CUvMRO9MKvF3y/

Comment: Maybe would be a good idea check on the browser's console, maybe something is happening with your code locally

Answer (score -1):

If you are not using Jquery make sure you run the script after the button element is created.

If you're using jquery replace window.onload for

```
$(function(){
 //Initial code goes here
});
```

or

```
$( document).ready( function(){
 //Initial code goes here
});
```

the reason is because window.onload , runs the script on the go, probably before the button is even created, with jquery you must wait for the document to be fully loaded in order to work with elements

Comment: This is false. `load` runs _after_ `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: i tried both and neither of these worked and it also doesn't explain why it works in IE but not chrome.

Answer (score -1):

One of solution put js file in before close tag `</body>` first jquery file, after yours, and you can remove `window.onload`

index.html

```
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="addinput" type="button" class="btn btn-default">add</button>
        <div id="addto"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./main.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

main.js

```
var buttonElement = document.getElementById("addinput");

if (buttonElement) {
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', addinput);
}

function addinput() {
    var input1 = '<div class="input-group mb-3"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Name</span></div><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"></div>';
    $("#addto").append(input1);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked i'm still getting nothing happening

Comment: May be you just forget add selector #addto on page?

Comment: This will work as it's in the same file as html, the issue is that when the JS is in another js file it wont work in chrome but will work in internet explorer

Comment: @adamWadsworth i updated, works of course fine, i am sure problem in you side(mb adblock or something else)

Comment: You were correct there is something broken on my chrome, I downloaded chrome portable (clean chrome) and it now works. This has wasted so much of my time. Thank you for your help. I don't know what is causing it though as i have disabled all my extensions