# Add EventListner not working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

I'm trying to execute a function as soon as an option is selected. My code works flawlessly in Firefox but there's no response or error in Google Chrome. I have tried different solutions found on StackOverflow but nothing helped. The solutions I tried include adding javascript as an external file. I tried Using window.addEventListener but nothing is working in chrome.

EDITED(THE SOLUTIONS I TRIED):

[solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9614476/15984741)

[solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51527560/15984741)

[solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62478598/15984741)

HTML:

```
<div class="col-12">
<label for="username" class="form-label">Select Plan</label>
<select id="selections" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option class="dropdown_option" id="1" value="plan1">plan1</option>
    <option class="dropdown_option" id="2" value="plan2">plan2</option>
    <option class="dropdown_option" id="3" value="plan3">plan3</option>
    <option class="dropdown_option" id="4" value="plan4">plan4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

JS(EDITED):

```
h = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown_option');

for (var i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
    h[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(this.innerHTML);
        retrieveplans(this.innerHTML);
    })
}
```

Comment: Why are you reselecting the same element? `g` is the same as `h[i]`?

Comment: So ... `g` is `h[i]`? Seems redundant

Comment: `I have tried different solutions found on StackOverflow` like what?  Can't tell what the issue is. Can you?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I removed that part, please check the edited code.

Comment: @JaromandaX I Added links to the solutions (Code) I tried.

Comment: No response no error ... are you sure? What response do you require?

Comment: Can you explain what `{% for plan in plans%}` is. Your tags don't help

Comment: @JaromandaX {% for plan in plans%} are from Django. They create more <options>
And yeah no error, the expected output (response) is a console.log but nothing appears in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246471/discussion-between-vaibhav-vishwakarma-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onclick on option tag not working on IE and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome)